# Memory-efficient string collection

Tags: c#, strings

My goal is to create a memory-efficient (immutable) collection of strings. The imagined use-case is checking for valid words in a Scrabble-like game.

[Wikimedia Commons](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Trie-vs-minimal-acyclic-fa.svg) has a pretty good summary of the data structure (author: Chkno):

[image]

(Image license: [Creative Commons Attribution-Share Alike 3.0 Unported](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/deed.en).)

For an input of `{ "tap", "taps", "top", "tops" }`, `StringCollection` should construct the figure on the right. The only difference is that instead of an EOW link, states are marked as final.

The algorithm for constructing the data structure is from the paper [*Incremental construction of minimal acyclic finite-state automata*](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=971842).

```
namespace Mjolka.Collections
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Text;

    /// <summary>
    /// Represents a memory-efficient collection of strings.
    /// </summary>
    [Serializable]
    public class StringCollection : IEnumerable<string>
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The initial state of the finite-state automaton.
        /// </summary>
        private readonly State initialState;

        /// <summary>
        /// The number of elements in the collection.
        /// </summary>
        private readonly int count;

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="StringCollection"/> class that contains
        /// the specified strings, where the strings are in lexicographic order.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="strings">
        /// The collection of strings that are in the new <see cref="StringCollection"/>, in
        /// lexicographic order.
        /// </param>
        /// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException">
        /// <paramref name="strings"/> is <c>null</c>.
        /// </exception>
        /// <exception cref="ArgumentException">
        /// An item in <paramref name="strings"/> is <c>null</c>.
        /// </exception>
        public StringCollection(IEnumerable<string> strings)
        {
            if (strings == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("strings");
            }

            var register = new Dictionary<State, State>(new StateComparer());
            using (var enumerator = strings.GetEnumerator())
            {
                if (!enumerator.MoveNext())
                {
                    return;
                }

                if (enumerator.Current == null)
                {
                    throw new ArgumentException("strings cannot contain null", "strings");
                }

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(enumerator.Current))
                {
                    this.initialState = new FinalState();
                }
                else
                {
                    this.initialState = new State();
                    AddSuffix(this.initialState, enumerator.Current.ToCharArray());
                }

                this.count = 1;

                while (enumerator.MoveNext())
                {
                    var word = enumerator.Current;
                    if (word == null)
                    {
                        throw new ArgumentException("strings cannot contain null", "strings");
                    }

                    var chars = word.ToCharArray();
                    int prefix;
                    var lastState = this.CommonPrefix(chars, out prefix);
                    if (lastState.HasChildren)
                    {
                        ReplaceOrRegister(lastState, register);
                    }

                    var suffix = new ArraySegment<char>(chars, prefix, word.Length - prefix);
                    AddSuffix(lastState, suffix);
                    this.count++;
                }
            }

            ReplaceOrRegister(this.initialState, register);
            register.Clear();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the number of strings contained in the <see cref="StringCollection"/>.
        /// </summary>
        public int Count
        {
            get { return this.count; }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Determines if the <see cref="StringCollection"/> contains the specified value.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="value">
        /// The value to locate in the <see cref="StringCollection"/>.
        /// </param>
        /// <returns>
        /// <code>true</code> if the <see cref="StringCollection"/> contains the specified value;
        /// otherwise, <code>false</code>.
        /// </returns>
        public bool Contains(string value)
        {
            if (value == null)
            {
                return false;
            }

            var state = this.initialState;
            foreach (var c in value.ToCharArray())
            {
                var nextState = state.Transition(c);
                if (nextState == null)
                {
                    return false;
                }

                state = nextState;
            }

            return state.IsFinal;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// The get enumerator.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>
        /// The <see cref="Enumerator"/>.
        /// </returns>
        public Enumerator GetEnumerator()
        {
            return new Enumerator(this);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// The get enumerator.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>
        /// The enumerator.
        /// </returns>
        IEnumerator<string> IEnumerable<string>.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return new Enumerator(this);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// The get enumerator.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>
        /// The enumerator.
        /// </returns>
        System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return new Enumerator(this);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Counts the number of states in the finite-state automaton.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>
        /// The number of states in the finite-state automaton.
        /// </returns>
        internal int CountStates()
        {
            var seen = new HashSet<State>();
            var stack = new Stack<State>();
            stack.Push(this.initialState);
            while (stack.Count > 0)
            {
                var state = stack.Pop();
                if (!seen.Add(state))
                {
                    continue;
                }

                foreach (var child in state.Children)
                {
                    stack.Push(child.State);
                }
            }

            return seen.Count;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Adds a suffix to a state.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="state">
        /// The state to add the suffix to.
        /// </param>
        /// <param name="suffix">
        /// The suffix to add to the state.
        /// </param>
        private static void AddSuffix(State state, IList<char> suffix)
        {
            var length = suffix.Count - 1;
            for (var i = 0; i < length; i++)
            {
                var newState = new State();
                state.AddEdge(suffix[i], newState);
                state = newState;
            }

            state.AddEdge(suffix[length], new FinalState());
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Replaces a state or inserts it into the register.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="state">
        /// The state to replace or insert into the register.
        /// </param>
        /// <param name="register">
        /// The register.
        /// </param>
        private static void ReplaceOrRegister(State state, IDictionary<State, State> register)
        {
            var child = state.LastChild;
            if (child == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            if (child.HasChildren)
            {
                ReplaceOrRegister(child, register);
            }

            State replacement;
            if (register.TryGetValue(child, out replacement))
            {
                state.LastChild = replacement;
            }
            else
            {
                register.Add(child, child);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the common prefix of a word and the finite-state automaton.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="word">
        /// The word to find the common prefix of.
        /// </param>
        /// <param name="prefixLength">
        /// The length of the common prefix.
        /// </param>
        /// <returns>
        /// The last <see cref="State"/> in the common prefix.
        /// </returns>
        private State CommonPrefix(IList<char> word, out int prefixLength)
        {
            var state = this.initialState;
            var length = word.Count;
            for (var i = 0; i < length; i++)
            {
                var next = state.Transition(word[i]);
                if (next == null)
                {
                    prefixLength = i;
                    return state;
                }

                state = next;
            }

            prefixLength = length;
            return state;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Represents a labeled edge from one state to another.
        /// </summary>
        [Serializable]
        private struct Edge
        {
            /// <summary>
            /// The edge label.
            /// </summary>
            public readonly char Label;

            /// <summary>
            /// The edge state.
            /// </summary>
            public readonly State State;

            /// <summary>
            /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="Edge"/> struct.
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="label">
            /// The edge label.
            /// </param>
            /// <param name="state">
            /// The edge state.
            /// </param>
            public Edge(char label, State state)
            {
                this.Label = label;
                this.State = state;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// The path segment.
        /// </summary>
        private struct PathSegment
        {
            /// <summary>
            /// The label.
            /// </summary>
            public readonly char Label;

            /// <summary>
            /// The depth.
            /// </summary>
            public readonly int Depth;

            /// <summary>
            /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="PathSegment"/> struct.
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="label">
            /// The label.
            /// </param>
            /// <param name="depth">
            /// The depth.
            /// </param>
            public PathSegment(char label, int depth)
            {
                this.Label = label;
                this.Depth = depth;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// The enumerator.
        /// </summary>
        public class Enumerator : IEnumerator<string>
        {
            /// <summary>
            /// The initial state.
            /// </summary>
            private readonly State initialState;

            /// <summary>
            /// The string builder.
            /// </summary>
            private readonly StringBuilder stringBuilder;

            /// <summary>
            /// The states to traverse next.
            /// </summary>
            private readonly Stack<State> states;

            /// <summary>
            /// The edges leading to the states on the stack.
            /// </summary>
            private readonly Stack<PathSegment> edges;

            /// <summary>
            /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="Enumerator"/> class.
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="stringCollection">
            /// The string collection.
            /// </param>
            public Enumerator(StringCollection stringCollection)
            {
                this.initialState = stringCollection.initialState;
                this.stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                this.states = new Stack<State>();
                this.states.Push(this.initialState);
                this.edges = new Stack<PathSegment>();
            }

            /// <inheritdoc />
            public string Current
            {
                get { return this.stringBuilder.ToString(); }
            }

            /// <inheritdoc />
            object System.Collections.IEnumerator.Current
            {
                get { return this.Current; }
            }

            /// <inheritdoc />
            public bool MoveNext()
            {
                // Move to the next FinalState, adding chars in the
                // path to this.stringBuilder.
                while (this.states.Count > 0)
                {
                    var state = this.states.Pop();
                    var depth = -1;
                    if (this.edges.Count > 0)
                    {
                        var edge = this.edges.Pop();
                        depth = edge.Depth;
                        if (depth < this.stringBuilder.Length)
                        {
                            this.stringBuilder.Remove(depth, this.stringBuilder.Length - depth);
                        }

                        var label = edge.Label;
                        this.stringBuilder.Append(label);
                    }

                    var children = state.Children;
                    if (children != null)
                    {
                        depth = depth + 1;
                        for (var i = children.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                        {
                            var child = children[i];
                            this.edges.Push(new PathSegment(child.Label, depth));
                            this.states.Push(child.State);
                        }
                    }

                    if (state.IsFinal)
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                }

                return false;
            }

            /// <inheritdoc />
            public void Reset()
            {
                this.stringBuilder.Clear();
                this.states.Clear();
                this.states.Push(this.initialState);
                this.edges.Clear();
            }

            /// <inheritdoc />
            public void Dispose()
            {
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Represents a state in the finite-state automaton.
        /// </summary>
        [Serializable]
        private class State
        {
            /// <summary>
            /// The edges out of the state.
            /// </summary>
            private Edge[] children = new Edge[0];

            /// <summary>
            /// Gets a value indicating whether the state has children.
            /// </summary>
            public bool HasChildren
            {
                get { return this.children.Length > 0; }
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Gets or sets the last edge out of the state.
            /// </summary>
            public State LastChild
            {
                get
                {
                    var length = this.children.Length;
                    return length > 0
                        ? this.children[length - 1].State
                        : null;
                }

                set
                {
                    var lastIndex = this.children.Length - 1;
                    var lastChild = this.children[lastIndex];
                    this.children[lastIndex] = new Edge(lastChild.Label, value);
                }
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Gets a value indicating whether the state is final.
            /// </summary>
            public virtual bool IsFinal
            {
                get { return false; }
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Gets the children.
            /// </summary>
            public Edge[] Children
            {
                get { return this.children; }
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Gets the state corresponding to the edge with the specified label out of the state,
            /// if it exists.
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="label">
            /// The label of the edge out of the state.
            /// </param>
            /// <returns>
            /// The <see cref="State"/> corresponding to the edge with the specified label.
            /// </returns>
            public State Transition(char label)
            {
                var length = this.children.Length;
                for (var i = 0; i < length; i++)
                {
                    var child = this.children[i];
                    if (child.Label == label)
                    {
                        return child.State;
                    }
                }

                return null;
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Adds an edge out of the state.
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="label">
            /// The label of the edge to the specified state.
            /// </param>
            /// <param name="state">
            /// The state.
            /// </param>
            public void AddEdge(char label, State state)
            {
                var length = this.children.Length;
                var newChildren = new Edge[length + 1];

                Array.Copy(this.children, newChildren, length);

                newChildren[length] = new Edge(label, state);
                this.children = newChildren;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Represents a final state in the finite-state automaton.
        /// </summary>
        [Serializable]
        private sealed class FinalState : State
        {
            /// <inheritdoc />
            public override bool IsFinal
            {
                get { return true; }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Represents a state comparer.
        /// </summary>
        private class StateComparer : IEqualityComparer<State>
        {
            /// <inheritdoc />
            public bool Equals(State left, State right)
            {
                if (left.IsFinal != right.IsFinal)
                {
                    return false;
                }

                var leftChildren = left.Children;
                var rightChildren = right.Children;

                if (leftChildren.Length != rightChildren.Length)
                {
                    return false;
                }

                for (var i = 0; i < leftChildren.Length; i++)
                {
                    var leftChild = leftChildren[i];
                    var rightChild = rightChildren[i];
                    if (leftChild.Label != rightChild.Label || leftChild.State != rightChild.State)
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                }

                return true;
            }

            /// <inheritdoc />
            public int GetHashCode(State obj)
            {
                unchecked
                {
                    var result = obj.IsFinal ? 17 : 521;
                    foreach (var child in obj.Children)
                    {
                        result = (31 * result) + child.Label.GetHashCode();
                        result = (31 * result) + child.State.GetHashCode();
                    }

                    return result;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The code and unit tests are [available on GitHub](https://github.com/mjolka/collections).

All feedback/improvements are welcome. There are some parts I'm not particularly happy with:

- The special-casing of the empty string in the constructor
- Using an `out` parameter in `CommonPrefix`
- All of `Enumerator.MoveNext`

**Edit**: Subclassing `State` and using `Edge[]` instead of `List<Edge>` were guided by profiling. Here are some stats from dotMemory:

Test input: [BritishWords.txt](https://github.com/mjolka/collections/blob/master/src/Mjolka.Collections.Tests/Resources/BritishWords.txt). 79,764 words, 776,045 bytes.

Build: .NET 4.5/x86/Release.

Code as posted here:

```
                                          Retained Bytes
StringCollection                               1,469,008
```

Using a boolean field for `IsFinal` instead of subclassing `State`:

```
StringCollection                               1,612,224
```

Using `List<Edge>` (and`TrimExcess`) instead of `Edge[]`:

```
StringCollection                               2,360,732
```

In comparison, using a `HashSet<string>` (which requires the strings to also be in memory):

```
                            Objects Count          Bytes
string                             79,764      2,509,260

                                          Retained Bytes
HashSet<string>                         1      1,448,432
                                               ---------
                                               3,957,692
```

Of course, for many applications, 2.5MB is just a rounding error, but sometimes [it matters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/jj681682(v=vs.105).aspx#BKMK_Memorylimitbyapptype). I'm just trying to reduce memory usage as a learning exercise.

Comment: I find a `Collection` suffix is a bit misleading. Client code may rightfully be expecting `ICollection` members. Also I'd throw an `ArgumentNullException` instead of an `ArgumentException` - you are, after all, throwing that exception because the value is `null`...

Comment: @Mat'sMug Good point about the suffix, suggestions for an alternative name are welcome :) I'm undecided about `ArgumentNullException` because it's not the argument itself that is null, but an element of the argument.

Comment: Why are you using an array for `children`? A `List<>` seems like it would make more sense.

Comment: @Snowbody it would, except I'm trying to use as little memory as possible. Those few extra bytes per state add up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For this answer, I'll work on the following assumptions, so tell me if any of them are wrong:

- You're most interested in memory efficiency
- You're not so interested in time efficiency, especially within the initial construction of the collection
- You're happy to use LINQ

### Enumerator

The first thing I notice here are the stacks. And the first thing that makes me think: recursion! You're not only worrying about keeping two stacks aligned, but you also have to keep track of how deep you are inside them. Taking advantage of the call stack to take care of that for you makes life a lot easier.

So start with the signature:

```
private IEnumerable<string> Next(State state, PathSegment? edge, StringBuilder builder)
```

You know the `State` and `PathSegment?` need to be in there because they're the ones in stacks. The way I've done it I've replaced the class with an iterator method, which necessitates the `StringBuilder` being passed back and forth rather than being kept as a class-level variable.

From there, it's fairly simple to rework what you have currently to a new version:

```
private IEnumerable<string> Next(State state, PathSegment? edge, StringBuilder builder)
{
    if (edge != null)
    {
        builder.Append(edge.Value.Label);
    }

    if (state.IsFinal)
        yield return builder.ToString();

    foreach (var child in state.Children)
    {
        var nextEdge = new PathSegment(child.Label, 0);
        foreach (var result in Next(child.State, nextEdge, builder))
            yield return result;
    }
    if(builder.Length > 0)
        builder.Remove(builder.Length - 1, 1);
}
```

Notice that by taking advantage of the call stack, `depth` isn't needed at all, we just remove the last character from the builder before exiting the method. This means that we can actually get rid of the `PathSegment` class altogether and use `Edge` directly instead!

After applying that, the next thing that stands out is this line:

```
foreach (var result in Next(child.State, child, builder))
```

It doesn't seem like we should have to pass both `child.State` and `child`. So let's simplify further:

```
private IEnumerable<string> Next(Edge edge, StringBuilder builder)
{
    var state = edge.State;
    if (state.IsFinal)
        yield return builder.ToString();

    foreach (var child in state.Children)
    {
        builder.Append(child.Label);
        foreach (var result in Next(child, builder))
            yield return result;
    }
    if (builder.Length > 0)
        builder.Remove(builder.Length - 1, 1);
}
```

Note that labels are now appended before calling into the method recursively, rather than at the beginning. This is so that we can do:

```
public IEnumerable<string> StringEnumerator()
{
    var entryEdge = new Edge('\0', initialState);
    return Next(entryEdge, new StringBuilder());
}
```

You can plonk this directly in your `StringCollection` class and use it for your `GetEnumerator`.

Comment: I'm posting this as is for now, I may come back and add more to it later if I get the time

Comment: Assumptions are all correct. Great answer, the enumerator has been a pain for me. I'll try out your suggestion today :)

Answer (score 13):

> ### StringCollection

#### Naming

`StringCollection` is, as I pointed out in the comments, a misleading name that suggests your type is implementing `ICollection<T>`. A better name is pretty hard to find though, since `EnumerableString` just looks weird, as `String` already implements `IEnumerable<char>`.

The only *"better"* name I can think of, is `Strings`... it's somewhat lame, granted.. but it's not misleading.

The `Contains` member method, because of how the C# compiler resolves method calls, will always be called over Linq's `Contains<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource>, TSource)` extension method; this may or may not be desired, and/or expected. Since you already have XML comments, you could add a `<remarks>` tag, and document that.

---

#### Duplication

You `return new Enumerator(this)` a lot. Why not have a `private IEnumerator GetEnumeratorInternal()` method that all `GetEnumerator()` methods could call?

---

#### Constructor

I wouldn't bother with the early return if the `MoveNext` returns `false`, since the `while` loop won't iterate in that case, and you'll no longer need to check whether `Current` is `null` outside the loop, and you can start incrementing the `count` within the loop instead of starting at 1.

---

> ### Enumerator

#### this

This is purely aesthetic, but I find the constructor... bulky:

> ```
> public Enumerator(StringCollection stringCollection)
> {
>     this.initialState = stringCollection.initialState;
>     this.stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
>     this.states = new Stack<State>();
>     this.states.Push(this.initialState);
>     this.edges = new Stack<PathSegment>();
> }
> ```

...compared to how I would have written it:

```
public Enumerator(StringCollection stringCollection)
{
    _initialState = stringCollection.initialState;

    _stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    _edges = new Stack<PathSegment>();
    _states = new Stack<State>();

    _states.Push(this.initialState);
}
```

By prefixing private fields with an underscore, you remove the need to qualify them in assignations like this.

---

#### Comments

These comments are redundant and useless. Remove them. Don't write XML comments just for the sake of writing XML comments; private members don't/shouldn't need XML comments:

> ```
> /// <summary>
> /// The initial state.
> /// </summary>
> private readonly State initialState;
>
> /// <summary>
> /// The string builder.
> /// </summary>
> private readonly StringBuilder stringBuilder;
> ```

Compare to:

```
private readonly State _initialState;
private readonly StringBuilder _stringBuilder;
```

XML comments that add no value, are just noise and clutter. Burn.

---

You're declaring a very short-lived variable in `MoveNext`, that can afford to disappear:

> ```
> var label = edge.Label;
> this.stringBuilder.Append(label);
> ```

`this.stringBuilder.Append(edge.Label);` is clear enough IMO.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I believe it's expected/desirable for classes implementing `IEnumerable<T>` to provide an efficient `Contains` method, with the guarantee that `x.Contains(y) == ((IEnumerable<T>)x).Contains(y)`.

Comment: The more I think about it, it seems the way to go is to implement `ICollection<string>`, return `true` for `IsReadOnly`, and throw `NotSupportedException`s for `Add` and `Remove`.

Comment: @mjolka Even better, implement [`IReadOnlyCollection<string>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh881542) (assuming supporting only .Net 4.5 is okay for you).

Comment: @svick thank you!! That's exactly what I want. Please feel free to add it to your answer. I found [`ReadOnlyCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132474(v=vs.110).aspx) but missed `IReadOnlyCollection<T>`.

Answer (score 4):

The biggest problem I found is that your code doesn't work when you have a shorter string (like `"a"`) after a longer string (like `"abc"`).

It's possible there are other cases where your code doesn't work, but I wasn't able to follow the logic of your code properly.

---

```
string.IsNullOrEmpty(enumerator.Current)
```

You already tested `Current` for `null`, so now you can only test it for `== string.Empty`.

---

```
using (var enumerator = strings.GetEnumerator())
```

This is ugly. I would prefer a normal `foreach` instead, though it would probably require changes in other methods.

---

```
register.Clear();
```

`register` is a local variable, that will become eligible for GC after the method exits. There is no reason to manually `Clear()` it just before that.

---

```
foreach (var c in value.ToCharArray())
```

`string` is enumerable, so you write just:

```
foreach (var c in value)
```

---

```
public Enumerator GetEnumerator()
IEnumerator<string> IEnumerable<string>.GetEnumerator()
```

This is usually done when `Enumerator` is a `struct`, which can make `foreach` more efficient (no heap allocations). But your `Enumerator` is a `class`, so doing this won't help you much.

---

```
public void AddEdge(char label, State state)
```

All that array copying might result in less used memory after the state machine is built, but it makes the building itself more memory-intensive and less efficient.

A better solution would be to use `List` here and then call [`TrimExcess()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132207) on all lists after you're done building.

---

```
private sealed class FinalState : State
{
    /// <inheritdoc />
    public override bool IsFinal
    {
        get { return true; }
    }
}
```

This doesn't seem to be worth creating a separate type for.

---

```
private class StateComparer : IEqualityComparer<State>
```

This seems to be the only reasonable way of comparing states, so I would make `State` implement `IEquatable<State>` instead.

Comment: This is great feedback, thank you! A couple of things though- strings must be in order, this is noted in the xml docs. Should I throw an exception if they're not? FinalState saves a few bytes per state, as opposed to a bool field. Same for using array over List.

Comment: @mjolka Oh, I overlooked those comments. Yeah, you should definitely throw a clear exception in that case. And I don't think those savings are worth it. Have you actually measured your code?

Comment: cool, I'll throw an exception. I've profiled this version and alternatives using dotMemory, and while the difference is negligible in the real world, I've set myself a goal of minimal memory usage - even if it means ugly code. It's a learning exercise. Might add some stats to the original post.

Comment: @mjolka ugly good code > artsy fartsy average code all day everyday.

Comment: @mjolka What about the case when that minimal memory usage means bad performance? Because that's what copying those arrays does. Also, you could save few more bytes by initializing `State.children` to `null`.

Comment: @svick I'm OK sacrificing performance during construction. Pretend it's a (literally) once-off cost, as the StringCollection is only built once during development, serialized as a game asset, and deserialized at program startup. Good point about initialising to null, that's worth adding to your answer :)

Comment: @svick I agree about GetEnumerator being ugly (and everything else I've not addressed in your answer). If you could provide an alternative that would be great.